# Audiobooks to learn about Infosec?

Tags: professional-education

I recently got homeland on a humble bundle and I've been getting really interested in Information Security so i want to keep learning and the best way i find is to listen to Audio books or podcast while drawing\walking\sleeping.

I've listened to Homeland and SnowCrash, i know the Cryptonomicon has an Audiobook but the one i found has a voice I don't really like.

Answer (score 0):

I'd love to hear about more Infosec Audiobooks/Podcasts. I think [Risky Business](http://risky.biz) is great and allways on the pulse of what's current. I personally like their sense of humor although it's not for everyone.

[Ghost in the Wires](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005HBO3BY) is pretty entertaining.

I had a look through Audible a few weeks back for educational infosec books but couldn't find much. I guess that anything with block of code or diagrams doesn't work so well as audio.